# Views to another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need some clarification. I know that building a database for the sole purpose of putting views in there is a bad idea. More difficult to track, no schema bound or indexing of the views. But I have some reporting people keep pestering me about it, is there any good arguments anyone can give me?

They basically want to have databases for different business users, with these views that interact with the data warehouse. So it will be 5ish additional databases that the sole purpose is for views.

Comment: I'd say that's what multiple schema in one database are for.

Comment: Can you do it with (default) schemas?

Comment: FYSA you can index a view. However, SCHEMAs seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you sure those "reporting people" want actual views? The fine upstanding reporting people otherwise known as my colleagues generally want more performant flattened facts tables.

Comment: So do your reporting people want to restrict access, or make access easier? This is not clear and the answer would depend on that.

Comment: @Gimby They do want actual views, really for them its about sorting. They dont like multiple schemas.

Comment: @ajeh No, its all about grouping views certain user groups would like into one database section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a "database for views".

That's the tail wagging the dog :)

You *CAN* have "views" of one or more tables into the database.  Or even of tables *between* databases.  It sounds like that's what you're looking for.

STRONG SUGGESTION: Read these articles:

- [MSDN: Scenarios for Using Views](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188250(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [SQL: Using Views](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-views.htm)

PS:
This might also be useful:

> **Schema**
>
> [MSDN: SQL Server Best Practices – Implementation of Database Object
> Schemas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095(v=sql.100).aspx)
>
> SQL Server 2005 implemented the concept of a database object schema.
>
> A schema is a distinct namespace to facilitate the separation,
> management, and ownership of database objects.
>
> It removed the tight
> coupling of database objects and owners to improve the security
> administration of database objects.
>
> **Views**
>
> [MSDN: Scenarios for Using
> Views](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188250(v=sql.105).aspx)
>
> Views are generally used to focus, simplify, and customize the
> perception each user has of the database.
>
> Views can be used as security mechanisms by letting users access data
> through the view, without granting the users permissions to directly
> access the underlying base tables of the view.
>
> Views can be used to provide a backward compatible interface to
> emulate a table that used to exist but whose schema has changed.
>
> Views can also be used when you copy data to and from Microsoft SQL
> Server to improve performance and to partition data.

Comment: "Tail wagging the dog" I love it :) I agree with you, I am implementing views for a lot of the source tables as a 1 to 1 relationship right now so I can change the underlying source tables in the future without service disruption.